# OpenFlow :: Howto Stream Images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, coverflow, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to use OpenFlow (http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/) in an iPhone App to stream files off of my server. How can I do this? Should I be using NSOperationQueue?

So far I have been able to:
* Use local files
* Use their demo from Flickr (which uses the Flickr API and library)

Code to load local images:

```
NSString *imageName;
 for (int i=0; i < 30; i++) {
  imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d.jpg", i];
  [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forIndex:i];
  [imageName release];
 }
 [(AFOpenFlowView *)self.view setNumberOfImages:10];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also need to do something like this too.

I was going to try the suggestion from this blog:

http://blogs.oreilly.com/digitalmedia/2008/02/creating-an-uiimage-from-a-url.html

See if that works for you!